# django: make html button-action dependent on state

Tags: html, django, web

What is the best way of handling the following fundamental situation:

Let's say I have a website where people can friend each other by clicking a button.
If two people are already friends, the same button should trigger a defriend action (in django).

One way of solving it would be to pass a state to the template/html file but since it is a such a reoccurring task I wonder if there is a standard way for handling such a situation; because state variables are not particularly nice.

Comment: Have you tried something? code?

Comment: Well I ment the question more in a conceptual way. The coding part won't be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no other way. You have to have a state defined by the existence of a row in a ManyToMany relationship between two persons.

Each time you generate a template, that state has to be passed onto the context of the template.

Now, if this state has to appear in many different views, you could use a [TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSOR](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-context-processors) to automatically add the state to each context.

This state could even be [cached](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/) to avoid hitting the database each time you render a template.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How about an AJAX component?

Comment: I  think that conceptually the action friend/unfriend is not on a time-scale of dynamic content. It happens with a time scale of several new pages. Of course you can have a button that changes appearance and action every time the user clicks (using dynamic content), but you still need a database driven mechanism, due to its own intrinsic time-scale.